# how to set value of input field of extension on console of Chrome inspect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

[image: I uploaded the image, please click here if you want to see]
I tried to set value of input field of extension on console of inspect.
It looks like set the value but value is none.

```
var inputbox = document.querySelector('.state-styles');
inputbox.value = "blablablabla";
```

But, the value of input field doesn't change on element of inspect.
This is extension.
I think the extension was made by react.
In case of OnChange event happen, the value of input will change. I think so.
Then, How can I set the value???
Please help me.

I want to know about the way that I can set the value of input field on extension.
[image: This is console of inspect]

Comment: React code is transpiled to JavaScript. So when you inspect, you are working with native HTML and JavaScript. Is there more info on what extension this is?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Are you expecting the *markup* in the browser's DOM inspector to change when setting the value?  If so then your expectation is simply incorrect.  If that's not what you mean, can you elaborate on the problem you're observing?

Comment: I am going to set the value of input field automatically using javascript in inspect.
After set the value of input field, button is enabled.
But, after set the value like my code, i can't see the value on inspect element and button is not enabled.

Comment: @bluewater: *"i can't see the value on inspect element"* - That is expected behavior.  Updating the value of an element doesn't change the DOM.  It sounds like you just have an incorrect expectation and there's no actual problem.  *"and button is not enabled"* - What button?  What would cause that button's state to change?  There's nothing in the code shown related to this.  Nobody can help you with code we can't see.

Comment: Hi, everyone, I uploaded image. please check.

Comment: @bluewater: That image doesn't really add any useful information to the question.  What exactly are you asking at this point?  If you're still expecting the DOM to change when setting an input value then your expectation is still wrong.  If you're trying to ask about a button then we still know exactly nothing about that button or what code interacts with it.  A picture of what a button kind of looks like tells us nothing about that code, much in the same way that a drawing of a car tells you nothing about a mechanical problem for a particular car.

Comment: I am not going to change dom.
<input value="">
I am going to set the value of input on console.
But it does not changed when i see on inspect element.
Also, If i type the input box manually, I can see the value on inspect element.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: @bluewater: *"I am not going to change dom [...] But it does not changed when i see on inspect element."* - Those are mutually exclusive statements.  You're not expecting the DOM to change, but you are expecting the DOM to change?  It doesn't work that way.  Updating a value in the way you demonstrate in the question does not change the DOM.  You can solve your problem by no longer expecting something which does not happen.  *"If i type the input box manually, I can see the value on inspect element."* - If the site is using React, it may be re-rendering the markup entirely with a value.

Comment: @bluewater: Overall... Please update the question to provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  We don't know what the website in question is doing.  We don't know anything about code you're not showing us.  All we know is the two lines of code shown, which (1) does not affect the inspected DOM and (2) has nothing to do with any button.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much for your answer.
It works well. Thank you again.
David Thank you for your try.
But all is good now.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

In React.js, directly manipulating the DOM using methods like querySelector and setting the value of an input element may not reflect the expected changes in the DOM. This is because React has its own virtual DOM (VDOM) that it uses to efficiently update the actual DOM.

Instead of directly manipulating the DOM, React encourages you to manage the state of your components and let React handle the updates to the DOM for you. Here's how you can achieve the desired behavior in React:

Declare a state variable using the useState hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

     function MyComponent() {
        const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

       // ...
     }
```

Update the inputValue state variable when you want to change the value of the input box:

```
   setInputValue("blablablabla");
```

Render the input element using the inputValue state variable:

```
<input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={e => 
                setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
```

By following this approach, React will manage the state of the input element and automatically update the DOM when the state changes.